# NuGet - Can not find 'Add Library Package Reference...'

Tags: nuget-package

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with MVC3 installed.
As I am in the process of learning NuGet basics, I was going through this tutorial 
http://maleevdimka.com/post/NuGet-Part-1.aspx

I should go for 'Add Library Package Reference...' option to add default available feeds.
However when I go to my web application project in VS 2010, I see something else - 'Manage NuGet Packages...'.
If I click this, I have a dialog box with available online packages each with Install button.

Is 'Add Library Package Reference...' option no longer available in VS 2010 and is replaced by 'Manage NuGet Packages...'?

Please guide!

Answer (score 5):

The link "Add Library Package Reference..." has been renamed to "Manage NuGet Packages..." in NuGet 1.4 the UI is still the same (with a few updates).

source:
http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1032

Answer (score 1):

The "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." option may not appear in the Tools->Library Package Manager menu in certain cases, such as when you're debugging(because you usually can't edit a solution while running) or if you don't have at least one file open/selected.  This tripped me up for a bit.